# Как исправить AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute values?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Подскажите пожалуйста, нужно, запретить, писать, в группе, кто, отписался, от канала, но получаю ошибку.

Ругается, на эту строку, при отписке, от канала.

```
Update.message.left_chat_member = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=channel_id, user_id=message.from_user.id)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код находится в этом хендлере

```
@dp.chat_member_handler()
async def user_joined_chat(message: types.ChatMemberUpdated):
```

Ошибка:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'values'

Answer (score 0):

Эта ошибка означает, что объект класса, был удалён из памяти и теперь имеет значение None(т.е. пустоту)

И теперь присваивается в свойство(values) какое-то значение:

```py
# Update.message стала None и поэтому появляется ошибка
Update.message.left_chat_member = ...
```

`тут похожие проблемы:`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something